# Azure B2C Custom Policy - Showing button on validation

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

It looks like there is not a lot of help and forums on the Azure B2C Custom policy framework.

I have used the following technical profile for my custom policy.

```xml
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress">
              <Metadata>
                <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
                <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
                <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
              </Metadata>
              <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
              <InputClaims>
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
              </InputClaims>
              <OutputClaims>
                <!-- Required claims -->
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
     
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
     
                <!-- Optional claims -->
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
              </OutputClaims>
              <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue" />
              </OutputClaimsTransformations>
              <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

This profile looks for the user and comes back with an error message if the user was not found in AD. However I want to show the user a button to sign up after the validation happens. How can I achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C Custom Policy is now a GA product and it has a lot of good documentation available.

What you want to achieve here very common and has been explained in starter pack. Its called a signuporsignin policy.
Walk through the article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom

You can also see the policies here
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa/TrustFrameworkBase.xml

Look at this technical profile https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L981

providing this metadata might help

```xml
             <Metadata>
                <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
                <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
                <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
              </Metadata>
```